# How can I plan a DR solution for an SAP Instance running on HP-UX

Tags: oracle, disaster-recovery, hp-ux, sap

I'm supporting an environment that runs SAP on HP-UX. The HP Blade running the SAP Instance is connected to IBM Storage over FC connection.

SAN Infrastructure is duplicated by redundant primary-secondary SAN switch and also primary secondary SAN enclosure.

However the blade / chasis remains as single point of failure.

We would like to deploy a solution where another remote instance can be created that's replicated with the primary instance and kept as a DR instance.

Any recommendation of commercial off the shelf products + other scripted method would be appreciated.

We do like NetIQ Platespin Protect concept, but it doesn't work for HP-UX.

Answer (score 2):

We are using HP "[Serviceguard](http://h71028.www7.hp.com/enterprise/us/en/os/hpux11i-serviceguard-disaster-recovery-solutions.html?=tab2) MetroCluster" on our SAP/Oracle servers, that makes fast DRP. ServiceGuard is provided with scripts to manage the database stop/start and monitoring.

That is quite robust, we tested it in real situation after a cooling failure initiated by a fire alert, temp was high, server auto shutdown, applications restarted in the other datacenter.

In your case Metrocluster will not works as there is no support for hardware replication with your IBM storage. There is "ServiceGuard Extended Distance" that should work for you, it uses software replication (mirroring). If your IO write rate is not too high that would do.

I didn't tested it, you would have to check the compatibility matrix, the best is to contact your HP support.